# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment with PyMongo (MongoDB API)

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to follow [MongoDB - Quick Guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_quick_guide.htm) and I'm getting following error:

```
alexus@mbp:~ $ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient('mongodb://192.168.99.100:32768/')
>>> db = client['test']
>>> collection = db['c']
>>> 
>>> obj = 'adc83b19e793491b1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f32e592fc:{tag1:value1}'
>>> print obj
adc83b19e793491b1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f32e592fc:{tag1:value1}
>>> json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'), sort_keys=True)
'"adc83b19e793491b1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f32e592fc:{tag1:value1}"'
>>> db.c.insert(json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'), sort_keys=True))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2199, in insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 578, in _insert
    gen(), check_keys, self.codec_options, bwc)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 546, in gen
    doc['_id'] = ObjectId()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "insert" call expects a valid object, not a string.
Did you mean something like that:

```
db.c.insert({'adc83b19e793491b1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f32e592fc':{'tag1':'value1'}})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue like you with PyMongo, and I found the following solution:

```
import json    

valuestr = json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'), sort_keys=True)
value = json.loads(valuestr) # <-- returned data is not string
db.c.insert(value)
```